# Tower Won't Roll Back Commit

Tags: commit, git-tower

I am trying to roll back to a particular commit using Tower v 1.4.16 with Mac 0SX v 10.6.8. When I right-click on the commit, the option to "Roll Back to This Commit" is greyed out. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

And problem solved - I did not have the (head) selected over in the left-had column. Once I clicked "master (HEAD)". The option to Roll Back to This Commit and Revert This Commit were available.

Comment: Oh good! it felt like a silly thing that I overlooked, but I left the question and answer up in case it helped someone else. Glad it did!

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely an easy thing to overlook.